# async information from MSSQL database

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I have a python webpage which pulls information from a MSSQL database with pyodbc.

This works, however since some queries that get run are quite heavy. the webpage can take 20-30 seconds to load.

I want to fix this, What would be the best way to run all queries once every 15-30 minutes and store that data locally on the server or locally and pull that data into the webpage instead of rerunning the query on page load.

I would like to have a relatively fast way for the webpage to acces the data so accesing the webpage would only take a 1-2 seconds max.

redis is really fast but isn't really suited as it is too simple. key-value pairs
the most advanced I really need is is a table with a few rows and columnes (always less than 10).

Is there a relatively fast way to store such data locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run into this when creating large reports.  Nobody will wait for a 30 second query, even if it's going back over 15 years of sales data.

You have a few options:

1. Create a SQL Job in the SQL Server Agent to run a stored procedure that runs the query and saves to a table.  (This is what I do)
2. Use a scheduled task to run the query and save it to another table.  I think python could drive it on a windows box, but never used it myself.  I would do it in .NET.
3. Sometimes creating a view is enough of a performance boost, but depends on your data and database setup.  In addition check if there are any indexes or other common performance gains you can make.

I really think #1 is elegant, simple, and keeps all the work in the database.